# How does Google Auto Suggest Works for Slow Internet Connections

Tags: javascript, search, solr, search-engine

I am pondering and looking after methods that Google (or other Websites) uses for Auto Suggest when the internet connection is slow (EDGE or 2G). Google provides Auto Suggest for mobile web browsers (Chrome, Safari, Opera, UC browser etc) which are not running on 3G.

I have a data set of 1,20,000 words and have solr at back end. The data is retrieved for a keyword from the DB in 100ms and sent to the client request via HTTP still the auto suggest does not work for slow mobile data connections (works for desktop site).

I have tried work arounds like creating a text file with 1,20,000 entries and stroing it in Js variable (txt file size 2.2 MB so imagine JS file size now with a JS variable) for 1st request and serving the rest from this variable. **SLOW**

Creating multiple text files for alphabets and rest same as above. **SLOW**

Trying local browser storage **Auto Suggest Still does not work on Mobile (2G)**

EDIT: My only motive to make the txt file is to save the HTTP requests.

**ANY SUGGESTIONS??**

Comment: Try returning only the more popular subset of the search possibilities... 10kb or so.
Don't return a 2.2MB file, that's way too big.

Comment: Hi @Etai, see the edit(second last line).

Comment: Politely, May I ask the reason for Downvote???

Comment: I don't understand what you meant with the text file... and I don't know who downvoted this.
Perhaps you can try returning the results only for 'ap' when 'ap' is typed, tops of 1kb file. Does it work for this scenario? Can you confirm that it's the file size which is the issue, and not something else?

Comment: I have a service that returns results for 'ap' (relevant) as soon as the user types it. But this service works very slow for mobile EDGE and 2G connections so i thought to store all the keywords in a txt file(on server) where when a user types 'ap' it makes 1 HTTP request and loads all the values in a JS variable and serves his first request. Now for next search the for ex 'sa' it does not make any HTTP request is searches this JS variable and serves the user. (Just a thought) Did not work either moreover the JS file gets loaded with heavy data

Comment: Sorry, but nothing I can help you with here without a working example.

If returning only 1kb of data is still too slow, and caching the results locally doesn't work either, then you have other problems.

Comment: You'll either have to cache a lot of data locally, or request the data when the user starts typing. As soon as you have three characters your data set will be significantly smaller and should be retrievable over a slow connection - the trick is to start doing it in the background as soon as possible and hide the delay while the user is typing. Do the first request with three characters, then filter in javascript form that.

Comment: Done this! get results for 3 characters, get all in a JS variable, serve the rest of requests from this JS varibale. SLOW :(